# error while call web service with restkit api objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, rest, web-services

I am trying to call web service and upload image,

There is a problem in the mapping, and I have spent many hours on it without success. The error I am getting is:

> Error Domain=org.restkit.RestKit.ErrorDomain Code=1001 "No mappable
>   object representations were found at the key paths searched."
>   UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=No mappable object representations
>   were found at the key paths searched., NSLocalizedFailureReason=The
>   mapping operation was unable to find any nested object representations
>   at the key paths searched: user The representation inputted to the
>   mapper was found to contain nested object representations at the
>   following key paths: message, success This likely indicates that you
>   have misconfigured the key paths for your mappings., keyPath=null,
>   DetailedErrors=( )}

and there method that call web service

```
[SVProgressHUD show];

        [delegate.objectManager.HTTPClient.defaultHeaders setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forKey:@"content-type" ];

        RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[SignUpResponse class]]; //create response and request mapping

        [responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"phone": @"phone",
                                                              @"device_type": @"device_type",
                                                              @"device_token": @"device_token",
                                                              @"type": @"type",
                                                              @"email": @"email",
                                                              @"identity": @"identity",
                                                              @"date": @"date",
                                                              @"status": @"status",
                                                              @"name": @"name",
                                                              @"activation": @"activation",
                                                              @"image": @"image",
                                                              @"id": @"id"
                                                              }];

        RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:responseMapping
                                                                                                method:RKRequestMethodPOST
                                                                                           pathPattern:@"AgentRegister"
                                                                                               keyPath:@"user"
                                                                                           statusCodes:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:200]];

        [delegate.objectManager.defaultHeaders setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forKey:@"content-type" ];
        delegate.objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType =RKMIMETypeFormURLEncoded;


        [delegate.objectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

        [delegate.objectManager addResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

        NSString *fcmToken = [FIRInstanceID instanceID].token;

        SignUpRequest *signUpRequest = [[SignUpRequest alloc]init];
        signUpRequest.phone = txtPhoneNumber.text;
        signUpRequest.email = txtEmail.text;
        signUpRequest.identity=txtIdOrCity.text;
        signUpRequest.device_type=@"IOS";
        signUpRequest.device_token=fcmToken;
        signUpRequest.type=@"1";


        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Logo"];


        // Serialize the Article attributes then attach a file
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] multipartFormRequestWithObject:signUpRequest method:RKRequestMethodPOST path:@"AgentRegister" parameters:nil constructingBodyWithBlock:^(id<AFMultipartFormData> formData) {
            [formData appendPartWithFileData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
                                        name:@"image"
                                    fileName:@"photo.png"
                                    mimeType:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"];
        }];

        RKObjectRequestOperation *operation = [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] objectRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult){

            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            if(mappingResult.array.count !=0){
                [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"goToVerify" sender:self];
            }else{

            }

            [delegate.objectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];
        }failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error){
            [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
            NSLog(@"%@",error.description);
            UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@".."
                                                                           message:@"حدث خطاء ما .. حاول مرة اخري" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

            UIAlertAction *okAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Ok" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * _Nonnull action) {

            }];
            [alert addAction:okAction];
            [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
            [delegate.objectManager removeResponseDescriptor:responseDescriptor];

        }];
        [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is telling you that nothing was available at the `user` path. For instance, if your response is JSON, there would be no root key called `user`, only `message` and `success`:

`{
  "user": "<- This key doesnt exist",
  "message": "<- There is something here",
  "success": "<- There is also something here"
}`

You most likely need to change your `keyPath` from `user` to something like `success.user`.